# How get the current page address and output as link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How get the current page address and output as link (With jQuery)
i find this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

1.
I want get the current page address on my site test.com/index.php?abc=1  change it and output as link, like :

```
<a id="onlythislink" href="test.com/gogogo/index.php?abc=1">link text</a>
```

2. I want get the current page address on my site test.com/gogogo/index.php?abc=1  change it and output as link, like :

   `<a id="onlythislink" href="test.com/index.php?abc=1">link text</a>`

Comment: 2  line this: <a id="onlythislink" href="test.com/index.php?abc=1">link text</a>

Comment: Why do you need the current location? You could hardcode the correct address to that link. If you need to edit the current location for the href, then please explain what exactly you want to do.